# _casterror (null check operator used on a null value) when trying to get directory

Tags: flutter, dart

Always getting Null at "await getExternalStorageDirectory();", no matter temporary or not.
How can i solve this ?

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

    return directory.path;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the device has external storage? It is a nullable getter.

Comment: getTemporaryDirectory getting null too :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to get permission?

Add this to your `android_manifest.xml`:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then you need to prompt the user to grant the permission before you can use it. For that, you’ll probably want to check out [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler).

After that, remember that it is still a nullable getter, and you’ll want to handle that scenario peacefully. If you have null-safety enabled, your `Future` should be returning `String?` instead of `String`.

Comment: Yes, added permissions to my manifest but this still not working
also i added request permission to storage by `var status = await Permission.storage.request();`, but this still null error at `await`

Comment: Finally i get request for storage on my device and clicked "yes", but there is still a null error D:

Comment: @Noako You should be using `await Permission.storage.request().isGranted` in an if condition which will handle both requesting and checking if it’s granted. Have you restarted the app since granting permission to see if maybe it has something to do with the way the request is written?